# 1 select query to sort rows according to 2 columns?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve something with one query. Here is my table structure knowing thay (id, id_attached) are a UNIQUE INDEX

```
id      id_attached     name
20      0               Name of row 1
21      0               Name of row 2
22      20              Name of row 3
23      20              Name of row 4
15      20              Name of row 5
```

Is it possible with **one query** to select rows in this order. I'll need to use a GROUP BY id but at the same time I'll need 2 separate rows for the row 2?

```
20  Name of row 1
  15   Name of row 5
  22   Name of row 3
  23   Name of row 4
21  Name of row 2
```

Comment: Is there any logic for this result?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I've always been impressed by the community's reactivity :) I want this results in order to make it clear for the client to understand that the rows 3 & 4 belong to the row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort like this:

```
SELECT *
from my_table
ORDER BY IF(`id_attached` is NULL, id, `id_attached`),id;
```

and for you second question:

```
SELECT * from my_table ORDER BY IF(`id_attached` = 0, id, `id_attached`),id;
```

the result is now the same in your question. Is it not correct please ask me again, sorry

**Sample**

```
mysql> select * from my_table;
+------+-------------+---------------+
| id   | id_attached | name          |
+------+-------------+---------------+
|    1 |        NULL | Name of row 1 |
|    2 |        NULL | Name of row 2 |
|    3 |           1 | Name of row 3 |
|    4 |           1 | Name of row 4 |
+------+-------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql> SELECT * from my_table
    -> ORDER BY IF(`id_attached` is NULL, id, `id_attached`),id;
+------+-------------+---------------+
| id   | id_attached | name          |
+------+-------------+---------------+
|    1 |        NULL | Name of row 1 |
|    3 |           1 | Name of row 3 |
|    4 |           1 | Name of row 4 |
|    2 |        NULL | Name of row 2 |
+------+-------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Sample with suborder**

```
SELECT * from my_table m ORDER BY IF(id_attached = 0, id, id_attached+0.1),id;
```

**Sample with new field**

This will automatic update the new field. It works only if ID is not AUTO_INC

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
add COLUMN myorder INT GENERATED ALWAYS
AS (
    IF(`id_attached` = 0, id<<1, (`id_attached`<<1) +1) 
    ) STORED
;

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX idx_myorder (myorder);
```

**result**

```
mysql> select * from my_table;
+----+-------------+----------------+---------+
| id | id_attached | name           | myorder |
+----+-------------+----------------+---------+
| 15 |          20 |  Name of row 5 |      41 |
| 20 |           0 |  Name of row 1 |      40 |
| 21 |           0 |  Name of row 2 |      42 |
| 22 |          20 |  Name of row 3 |      41 |
| 23 |          20 |  Name of row 4 |      41 |
+----+-------------+----------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Wow, that's magic, didn't think about this. Thanks a lot :)
However, i just forgot a little detail that may change the results. I need to use a GROUP BY because of some LET & INNER JOINS. I'll update my initial post so you can better understand my need. Thanks again

Comment: @Websphere - i have update my answer for you second question. please test it again

Comment: actually it doesn't output the results i want, I'll need the row id 2 to appear twice as it's considered as regular row, and also attached to tow id 1 (please see the output results in my initial post)

Comment: Hi, just to let you know, a simple `GROUP BY id, id_attached` did the trick :) thanks @Bernd for your time ;)

Comment: Hi @Bernd, I've just realised a case in which the query doesn't work properly: It's when one of the attached products has a smaller ID then the parent product (row 5 in my example). then it's the row 5 which is displayed first and the hierarchy isn't respected :/ Any idea how to fix it? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Websphere - i am back in 1 hour and check it then direcly

Comment: how can i find out which row is displayed first, second ,..., or last. can you give me a sample please why which row ist displayed in which order ?

Comment: Following the examples I gave in my initial message, the first row should be 20 because it's considered as parent row, followed by 15, 22 & 23 (any order), because they are considered as children rows of row 20.

Comment: @Websphere - try this please **SELECT *
from my_table m
ORDER BY IF(`id_attached` = 0, id, `id_attached`+0.1),id;**

Comment: You rock @Bernd :) I swear i would have got you a beer if you were next to me :) very clever, thanks  ;) I'll keep moving on and will let you know if i discover any other case where it doens't work properly :) cheers

Comment: @Websphere -  if have add 2 samples in my answer. one creates a new field that automatic generates the sortorder

Comment: Thanks @Bernd for your update. I'll try your second solution and will let you know if I ever face a problem ;) Have a lovely week-end